# "TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects" in KerasRegression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression

I'm creating a simple regression neural network in Keras. However, when I try to run it as follows

```
   seed = 7
   numpy.random.seed(seed)

   dataset = numpy.loadtxt("instancesFipo.txt", delimiter=", ")
   #testset = numpy.loadtxt("instancesFipo6.txt", delimiter=", ")

   Xtrain = dataset[:,0:8] #All rows, first 8 columns
   Ytrain = dataset[:,8]  #All rows, 9th column

   model = Sequential()

   #Create layers of neural net
   model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer='normal', 
   activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))

   #Create loss function and algorithm
   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') 

   estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

   kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)

   results = cross_val_score(estimator, Xtrain, Ytrain, cv=kfold)
   print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

I'm getting "TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects", which is induced by the call to `cross_val_score`. Not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated and thanks!